# How to output random integer for duplicated node group

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to create a node group that outputs a random integer every time it's duplicated (without it needing you to put any different input value to it).

Is that even possible?
That is okay if some other node/nodes are going to it's input, but even better would be without, so if it was an independent node group.

I'm thinking of something about white noise.... not sure

Doesn't every node in the node graph have an ID? Why can't we use that as the seed for the random nodes perhaps?

We have 'Self Object' and 'Object Info' nodes, can we have 'Self Node' and 'Node Info' nodes?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The only way I could think is a driver for the seed, but driver's don't get duplicated, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you could script something in Python to do something like that but it would be a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it is possible :)

[Tweet1](https://x.com/fishwfeet/status/1757153187419611396), [Tweet2](https://twitter.com/iscream3d/status/1757195199984333110)

[image]